# Array fill not working as expected

Tags: arrays, vba

I am trying to fill an array of length 300 with the same value using VB here is my code:

```
Dim counter As Integer
If (value = True) Then
    For counter = LBound(arrLowThresholds) To UBound(arrLowThresholds) Step 1
        arrLowThresholds(counter) = LOG_TEST_LOW_THRESHOLD
        arrHighThresholds(counter) = LOG_TEST_HIGH_THRESHOLD
    Next
End If
```

The problem with this is that only the first element of the arrays is being filled.
Note that some of the variables are declared elsewhere that is the reason that the declaration is not visible.

`arrLowThresholds` and `arrHighThresholds` are the arrays while `LOG_TEST_LOW_THRESHOLD` and `LOG_TEST_HIGH_THRESHOLD` are the variables

Comment: The code you have posted looks fine.  The problem is likely somewhere else.  Have you tried using the debugger to step through and see what happens and check that every variable is as you expect?  Alternatively, add some more code to your question to make it a complete working example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I debugged through it and seems that everything is ok. The problem i cannot post the declarations is that the vbcode here is part of another Development Kit and this is just an extension forexample with excel in this case its MOVICON (an engineering SCADA program)

Comment: What is the behavior when debugging?  Does it go through the for loop only once?  What is the value of `UBound(arrLowThresholds)` when you debug?

Comment: Yes it goes once and the value is 299

Comment: Is this the actual code copied and pasted here, or did you type it in to the question?

Comment: No that is the actual code

Comment: The code obviously isn't VBScript. Is it VBA? VB6? VB.net? What is the actual value of `LBound` and `UBound` for both arrays?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Glad someone decided to ask this, how come it takes six comments before the actual language the OP is using versus the tagged language in the question is questioned?

Comment: And are the bounds of arrHighThresholds the same than those from arrLowThresholds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making a local array to use with the for loop.  Then I copied the contents to the array I am actually using.